# Gnuplot x(y) smoothing

Tags: gnuplot, smoothing

How do I smooth the data presented in the form x(y)? Gnuplot smoothing function of to invalid handles such cases.

---

As an example:

File(T-L.dat):

```
0.00    0.0
0.10    0.1
0.15    0.2
0.40    0.3
0.60    0.4
0.50    0.5
0.60    0.6
0.40    0.7
0.15    0.8
0.10    0.9
0.00    1.0
```

[What I want](https://yadi.sk/i/hNeMO9b9bkQT4).

Gnuplot session:

```
knkd@SCP71:~/MEAS/HEAT$ gnuplot

        G N U P L O T
        Version 4.6 patchlevel 4    last modified 2013-10-02 
        Build System: Linux x86_64

        Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2013
        Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

        gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
        faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
        immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot> plot "T-L.dat" with lines
```

[What I have](https://yadi.sk/i/f8KXGJ8dbkQUJ).

Add smooth:

```
gnuplot> plot "T-L.dat" with lines smooth csplines
```

Result not good too (only 2 links, sorry).

Other features also not give the result that I wanted to.
But really I need a spline.

Comment: Could you please invest a bit more time in asking a question? Do you want to fit a parabola to a set of data points, or do you only want to plot a parabola? So what is the part of your code which isn't working?

Comment: [Result not good too](https://yadi.sk/i/UE3k8hvEbkQUR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, gnuplot can smooth with splines only data of the form `y(x)`. For this, the data is rendered monotonic in x before smoothing it. You data is symmetric with respect to y, this is why you get a straight line as result of the smoothing.

In order to smooth your data with respect to `y`, you must first exchange the axes and save the result of the smoothing to a temporary file. This is then plotted with the correct axis selection:

```
set table 'T-L-smoothed.dat'
plot 'T-L.dat' using 2:1 smooth csplines
unset table
plot 'T-L-smoothed.dat' using 2:1 with lines, 'T-L.dat' with points pt 7
```

[image]