# gnuplot smooth interpolation does not maintain data order

Tags: gnuplot

Here's my data:

```
data.txt (1st column is X; 2nd column is Y):
30 16
26 24
28 30
73 36
```

When I chart this in excel using "scatter with smooth lines", I get a picture like this:

[image: desired chart from excel]

However, I am unable to find an equivalent in gnuplot. Basically, when I do something like this:

```
plot 'data.txt' u 1:2 w p, 'data.txt' u 1:2 smooth csplines lw 2 notable
```

The data in the x-axis is first sorted before doing the smooth interpolation. This destroys the order of the data and results in a funky chart like this:

[image: problem chart from gnuplot]

I have tried every other smooth option, bezier is an improvement  but does not connect 2 of my data point. Wondering if this is even possible to do in `gnuplot`. Thank you!

Comment: If you know your data is monotonic in y you can try the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26129986/2604213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible in gnuplot.  The meaning of smooth lines in Excel and smooth in gnuplot are not really the same.

In Excel, it does mean to use smooth lines instead of straight lines.

In gnuplot it means to apply one of many possible transformations to the data.  If you read the documentation on each one, you will see that almost all of them say that they first "make the data monotonic", which means that the data is first sorted.  Notice as well, that most of them do not work with the original data, but some transformation of the data.

If it is a feature that you need, I see no obvious reason why it isn't something that could be added (a *smoothlines* plot style).  The gnuplot page on sourceforge does allow users to submit feature requests.  See the [feature request page](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/?source=navbar) to do that.

Comment: Thank you! I will submit a feature request

Comment: @donkey, You're welcome.  If you find an answer helpful, please consider accepting it.  You are under no obligation to do so, but this awards both the author and yourself with a small amount of reputation, and lists the question as answered.  Remember also that you can upvote particularly helpful answers on your own questions or any other question.