# I need to plot frequency distribution (on the Y-axis) of a one column data file with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica

Using Gnuplot, we can plot the frequency of a one column data file with the command

> plot 'name of the file' smooth frequency w l

My problem here is that, the I need the frequency to be on the Y-axis instead of the X-axis. Is there a trick to actually do that. I have already tried

> plot 'name of the file' using 2:1 smooth frequency w l

But it doesn't work.

If there is also a way to do that in mathematica, I will be happy to Know.
ThanKs You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26129986/2604213

Answer (score 2):

```
BarChart[{2, 5, 6}, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLegends -> Map[ToString, Range[5]]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
data = {{0.118082595966, 0.0139434994702}, {0.232690587709, 
    0.0541449096085}, {0.323755025675, 
    0.10481731665}, {0.635064375908, 0.403306761548}, {1.03995593543, 
    1.08150834764}, {1.24757861309, 1.55645239584}, {1.24985914502, 
    1.5621478824}, {1.28010876631, 1.63867845358}, {1.39387084749, 
    1.94287593949}, {1.61826799763, 2.61879131215}};
g = ListLinePlot[data, ImageSize -> 300];
g2 = Show[g /. x_Line :> Reverse[x, 3], ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic];
Row[{g, g2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what I need is a normal frequency vs event plot with line, not with boxes.

Comment: @Rodrigues Where is the data?

Comment: @Rodrigues How about now?